# Low-risk option for replacing CComVariant?

Tags: c++, mfc, com

I have a legacy Windows project (no tests) which I am trying to get to cross-compile on Linux.  It contains a number of MFC types which have spilled throughout the project, but the most troublesome in my case seems to be `VARIANT` & `CComVariant`.  They are widely used, and large scale refactoring to use std::variant and/or fundamental types is risky.

**Is there an option that is lower risk?**

*Background: The intention is to keep the COM interfaces (behind compiler flags) for the Windows project and add new interfaces (using something like RabbitMQ or gRPC) for Linux. The Linux project would not interface with external COM applications. Eventually, we would replace COM altogether.*

Comment: A [VARIANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/variant-structure) structure is used to pass arbitrary data across COM interfaces. It has documented ABI layout requirements. Does your Linux-based build system understand COM rules, and produces ABI-compatible structure layouts?

Comment: I am in the planning phase and a newb to Linux dev, so my Linux-based build system is not completely defined.  I have created a basic CMake project with the intention to use probably gcc.

It is worth noting that, in some cases, this project is using these types internally - without the values ever being sent to another application.

Comment: Added clarification to question...

Comment: You mean you've used CComVariant internally, ie. outside of COM / Automation? CComVariant is "just" a wrapper, it relies on Windows library (oleaut32, etc. and possibly on some 20-years old bugs...) to work, so it's not that easy to port. If you really want to keep it, you'll have to reimplement it, including the Windows part (like VariantChangeType...).

Comment: Use `CComVariant` with ATL headers, there is no need for MFC.

Comment: @SimonMourier Right, I understand.  Yes, what I meant was that, in some cases, this project uses CComVariant for things that don't end up crossing a COM boundary.